# Changing stored JSON's field's value with slick-pg

Tags: json, postgresql, slick, circe, slick-pg

I'm using `slick-pg` with `circe-json` and I'm a bit stuck. I wonder is it possible to modify not the whole JSON, but only the value of a field?
I can update JSON like this:

```
    db.run {
      questQuery.filter(_.json.+>>("name") === name.bind)
        .map(_.json)
        .update(newQuestJson)
    }
```

But is there a way to update only one field? Something like this:

```
db.run {
      questQuery.filter(_.json.+>>("name") === questName.bind)
        .map(_.json.+>>(field))
        .update(newValue)
    }
```